# Node JS-mssql SQL injection warning for param. While executing Stored Procedure

Tags: node.js, sql-server, node.js-typeorm

```js
const createAllocation=async (allocation)=>{
    try{
        let [result, error] = await sp_executeSingle(DB.sps.addAllocation, [
            ['fk_UserID ', TYPES.Int, allocation.userID],
            ['fk_PortfolioID', TYPES.Int, allocation.portfolioID],
            ['isAllocated', TYPES.Bit, allocation.isAllocated],
            ['AmountRequested', TYPES.Decimal, allocation.AmountRequested],
            ['AmountActual', TYPES.Decimal, allocation.AmountActual],
            ['WineShsActual', TYPES.Int, allocation.WineShsActual],
            ['WhiskeyShsActual', TYPES.Int, allocation.WhiskeyShsActual],
            ['AutoShsActual', TYPES.Int, allocation.AutoShsActual],
            ['DiamondShsActual', TYPES.Int, allocation.DiamondShsActual],
            ['IsSettled', TYPES.Bit, allocation.IsSettled]
            
        ]);
        if (!!error) return [null, error];
        return [result, null];
    }
    catch(err){
        return [null, 'An unexpected error occurred while creating allocation'];
    }
}
async function sp_executeSingle(sp, params = []) {
    try {
        const pool = await poolPromise;
        const rows = await pool.request();
        params.forEach((param) => {
            rows.input(param[0], param[1], param[2]);
        });
        const result = await rows.execute(sp);

        return [result.recordset[0], null];
    } catch (err) {
        return [null, err.message];
    }
}
```

I am trying to execute the stored procedure through generic function all the other stored procedure work perfect but the one I am listing down show warning of SQL injection

[This is the generic method used for executing store procedures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RubaD.png)

[This is the stored procedure with inputs it show warning if SQL injection on fk_UserID param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEYgO.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for replying .I just added the code image i thought i might be doing some mistake in my code so that can be corrected instantly.

Comment: Sure, so post your code as formatted text not image

Comment: @DaleK i make it clear  i hope now you can understand it better .Waiting for the soution.